# Passing Parameter from conf in Airflow PostgresOperator

Tags: python, postgresql, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow-webserver

Want to access the config passed in the data in the API call

```
curl --location 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/dags/postgres_operator_dag/dagRuns' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
    "conf": {
        "seller_id": "test_seller"
    }
}'
```

Want to access seller_id in the sqlquery in PostgresOperator

```
with DAG(dag_id="postgres_operator_dag", start_date=datetime(2020, 2, 2), schedule_interval=None) as dag:
# seller_id = context['dag_run'].conf['seller_id']. Cant access context here

connection_source_check = PostgresOperator(
    task_id="fetch_connection_details",
    postgres_conn_id="postgres_connection",
    sql=f"""select c.name as connection_name, c.id as connection_id, a.name as source_name, a.id, a.actor_type as 
    source_id from "connection" c left join actor a on  a.id=c.source_id where a.name=%(seller_id)s;""",
    parameters={'seller_id': '{{ dag_run.conf["seller_id"] }}'},
    dag=dag
)
```

The above task returns no data. But when I hardcode parameters as

```
parameters={'seller_id': 'test_seller'}
```

It works.
Also Tried having sql file with params but with no effect.

This approach too doesnt work. It considers {{ dag_run.conf["seller_id"] }} as a string rather than evaluating the expression to test_seller and doesn't make the right query

```
with DAG(dag_id="postgres_operator_dag", start_date=datetime(2020, 2, 2), schedule_interval=None) as dag:

connection_source_check = PostgresOperator(
    task_id="fetch_connection_details",
    postgres_conn_id="postgres_hogwarts_connection",
    sql=f"""select c.name as connection_name, c.id as connection_id, a.name as source_name, a.id, a.actor_type as
        source_id from "connection" c left join actor a on  a.id=c.source_id where a.name= '{{ dag_run.conf["seller_id"] }}' ;""",
    dag=dag
)
```

This approach gives a syntax error -

psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "{"
LINE 2: ...ft join actor a on  a.id=c.source_id where a.name={ dag_run....

```
with DAG(dag_id="postgres_operator_dag", start_date=datetime(2020, 2, 2), schedule_interval=None) as dag:

connection_source_check = PostgresOperator(
    task_id="fetch_connection_details",
    postgres_conn_id="postgres_hogwarts_connection",
    sql=f"""select c.name as connection_name, c.id as connection_id, a.name as source_name, a.id, a.actor_type as
        source_id from "connection" c left join actor a on  a.id=c.source_id where a.name={{ dag_run.conf["seller_id"] }};""",
    dag=dag
)
```

What is the right approach to access the seller_id value that was passed in the curl request data.

Comment: why not just put the parameter directly into the SQL query? e.g. `sql=f"""select ... from ... where a.name={{ dag_run.conf["seller_id"] }};"""`

Comment: parameters is not one of the template fields, so you cannot put jinja template in that argument. See https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-postgres/stable/_api/airflow/providers/postgres/operators/postgres/index.html#airflow.providers.postgres.operators.postgres.PostgresOperator

Comment: @mck
Already tried with using it directly in the query with {{dag_run.conf['seller_id'] }} but it gives a syntax error - syntax error at or near "{"
Any way to build the query from the api data?

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the complete code that you have tried to run, and the complete error message?

Comment: @mck
Done with adding all the tried ways

Answer (score 0):

I would first try a debug task to ensure the seller_id is being properly passed to the dagrun config using below

`

```
def print_request_id(**kwargs):
    request_id = kwargs['dag_run'].conf.get('seller_id')
    print(f"Rendered seller_id: {seller_id}")

debug_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='debug_task',
    python_callable=print_request_id,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag
)
```

`
Also I dont think your sql needs to be f string to evaluate the jinja. You can change that to as below and try

```
connection_source_check = PostgresOperator(
    task_id="fetch_connection_details",
    postgres_conn_id="postgres_hogwarts_connection",
    sql="select c.name as connection_name, c.id as connection_id, a.name as source_name, a.id, a.actor_type as
        source_id from connection c left join actor a on  a.id=c.source_id where a.name= '{{ dag_run.conf["seller_id"] }}' ;,
    dag=dag
)
```